# How can i add logs of user's activity to a table in XAF?

Tags: c#, devexpress, xaf

I have a `Log` table and I need to add user's `activities` (especially security related).

For instance, If a user changes her password or logs in to the software then i will add `"password changed"` or `"user logged in"` string to a table. I think I should override the default `password change action` as explained [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/CustomDocument2727)

Am I correct and what is the corresponding action? Is it provided by XAF? I couldn't find anything in the [documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#xaf/CustomDocument2670). In fact, I also don't know how to add it to the table, I only logged some text to a `txt` file until now.

Answer (score 2):

Like @shamp00 says above, The [Audit Trail Module](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/CustomDocument2782) does this already and quite well. The audit trail module when enabled logs **everything** so all you have to do is write code to display only the information you want :-) 
Now unfortunately the password property is readonly so cannot be accessed but you can monitor all other user changes including a **password reset** since this triggers a change in the "change password on next logon" property.

All you need to do is

1. Add the Audit Trail Module to your project.
2. Add this snippet to **the specific object you would like to audit**

> ```
> private XPCollection<AuditDataItemPersistent> userAuditTrail;  
> public XPCollection<AuditDataItemPersistent> UserAuditTrail  
> {  
>   get  
>       {  
>           if(userAuditTrail == null)  
>           {  
>               userAuditTrail = AuditedObjectWeakReference.GetAuditTrail(Session, user);  
>           }  
>       return userAuditTrail;  
>        }
> }
> ```

To get this to work for me, I created an object called employee that inherited from `DevExpress.ExpressApp.Security.Strategy.SecuritySystemUser` because we want to extend the SecuritySystemUser to not only add full employee details (first name, last name and address details) but also to add auditing. Now because the password property is read-only, we cannot audit changes to it.
Since you are using Devexpress Universal you have the source code and so you can change the bits you don't like and recompile them to suit your needs. Consider putting adding the snippet below to the "change my password action".

> AuditDataItem customDataItem = new AuditDataItem(myAuditedObject,
>   null, 
>       "CustomOldValue", "CustomNewValue", AuditOperationType.CustomData);
>   AuditTrailService.Instance.AddCustomAuditData(mySession,
>   customDataItem); AuditTrailService.Instance.SaveAuditData(mySession);

Then for the time-stamp, you can extend the controller for each event you would like to log (like the logon) and add the [time to your audit log](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/CustomDocument2783/9) using the snippet above.
I hope this helps you. I will continue to look into it though.

Answer (score 1):

This is what [the audit trail module](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/CustomDocument2782) does.

If you need to add custom data to the audit trail, see the section named [Add Custom Data to the Audit Log](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/CustomDocument2783/9).